# jQuery Datepicker issues with minDate & maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Currently I am using the following code in order to setting the Date picker functionality -

```
$("#datepicker").click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" );
});
```

But if I remove the "show" from parameter. it doesn't work and I want to add some more parameters like **minDate**, **maxDate**.

Please help How can I do it with "show" parameter.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as an options like

```
$("#datepicker").click(function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        maxDate: yourMaxDate,
        minDate: yourMinDate
    }).datepicker("show");
});
```

---

I don't know why you are using a click handler to initialize the datepicker.... you can just do

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: yourMaxDate,
    minDate: yourMinDate
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y53sW/)

---

After the plugin initialization, if you want to update the value of options, you can use the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'optioname', optionvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change using `option`

```
$("#datepicker").click(function() {
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'minValue', new Date(startDate));
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxValue', new Date(endDate));
}

or...
    $("#datepicker").click(function() {
    $(this).datepicker('option', { minValue: new Date(startDate),
                                      maxValue: new Date(endDate) });

}
```